# nginx обратный прокси-сервер не работает

Tags: nginx, proxy, apache2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здравствуйте. У меня такая беда. Есть некая сеть. Интеренет подключен на Микротике, через NAT проброшены порты 80 и 443 на прокси nginx 192.168.88.225 (Mad-PC2), а еще есть Apache2 веб-сервер на 192.168.88.238 (Mad-PC3), слушающий порт 8080, и вот, мне надо, чтобы по запросу типа "test.madmentat.ru" была переадресация c Mad-PC2 на Mad-PC3.
На Mad-PC3 сделано такое:
/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 8080
```

Далее в /etc/apache2/apache2.conf прописано

```
<Directory /data/webserver/test>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

В /etc/apache2/apache2/sites-available/test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin  mypost@madmentat.ru
    ServerName   test.madmentat.ru
    ServerAlias  www.test.madmentat.ru
    DocumentRoot /data/webserver/test

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

На Mad-PC2 установлен nginx. Там в папке /etc/nginx/sites-available создан файл mad.conf со следующим содержанием:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.madmentat.ru www.test.madmentat.ru;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.88.238:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name madmentat.ru www.madmentat.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.88.238:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему лыжи не едут?!

Comment: так а в чем проблема то? Не переадресовывает? Переадресовывает не туда? Другая какая ошибка?

Comment: Да просто не переадресовывает, пишет "Unable to connect"

Comment: ввожу в адресной строке http://test.madmentat.ru - и нефига.

Comment: __Unable to connect__ на чьей стороне пишет, на апаче или нжиниксе в логах? Или тупо в браузере? Может проблема не в реверсе, а в NATе?

Comment: _test.madmentat.ru Address:  31.134.139.98_ это точно адрес вашего микротика?

Comment: 31.134.139.98 - внешний "белый" IP на микротике, а "Unable to connect" это тупо в браузере, тоже снаружи. В NATе, мне кажется, вряд ли... Там ведь трудно что-то перепутать...

Comment: а в логах нжиникса что? он фиксирует, что до него запрос дошел вообще? Если бы нжиникс не проксировал, то он вывел бы страницу ошибки нжиникса. Похоже, что нат не пробрасывает запросы

Comment: Я подправил конфиг nginx, добавил туда строчки "access_log /var/log/nginx/test.log;" и "error_log /var/log/nginx/test-error.log;", в итоге после неудачного подключения указанные файлы остаются пустыми. Я не знаю, может быть, в nginx есть какие-то еще логи?

Comment: По поводу NAT я сомневаюсь вот почему. test.madmentat.ru:8080 прекрасно работает. Правила для 80 и 443 прописаны аналогично. Если я меняю там последний октет IP c 225 на 238, то спокойненько попадаю на свой Апач и все в порядке. Тут вся разница в 2-х цифрах, их невозможно перепутать.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину, почему не работал nginx. Оказалось, что на том же компе, который Mad-PC2, был установлен Апач!..